# Calculating the order of the multiplicative group $k^\times$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $k$ be a field of cardinality $64$.

**1.** What is the order of the multiplicative group $k^\times$ of invertible elements of $k$?
What are the possible orders of elements of $k^\times$?

**2.**
Let $d\geq0$ be an integer. Show that $k^\times$ contains at most $d$ elements of order $d$.

**3.** Hence prove that $k^\times$ is a cyclic group.

**What I have tried so far:**

I have determined that the order of the multiplicative group is 63. Hence the possible orders are the factors of 63.

I know that for question 3, a group of order n is cyclic iff it contains an element of order n.

Comment: If you know what a field is, then surely Question 1 is very easy, and it has nothing to do with Euler's Totient Formula.

Comment: @DerekHolt so if the order is 63, how to I find out the possible order of elements of $k^\times$

Comment: The possible orders are the numbers that divide $63$.

Comment: You use the fact that, in any field, there are at most $d$ solutions to the equation $f(x) = 0$, for any polynomial $f$ of degree $d$. So, in particular, there are at most $d$ elements with $x^d=1$ for all divisors $d$ of $63$.  Then by counting you will find that there has to be an element of order $63$.

Comment: Part 1 does not tell you that there is an element of order $63$. That is what you are trying to prove.

Answer (score 3):

Hints.

1. $k$ is a *field*. How many elements does $k^\times$ have?
2. What equation does an element of order $d$ satisfy?
3. Add up the number of elements by order.

Comment: if k is a field with 64 elements and $k^\times$ = $k$ \ {${0}$} thus $k^\text{x}$ has 63 elements?

Comment: @B24Panther Yes.

Comment: @Rox If $G$ is a group with identity element $e$, then the order of an element $x$ is the least positive integer $n$ such that $x^n = e$. When $G = k^\times$ then the identity element is $1$. Since $k$ is a ring, we can perform subtraction; thus elements of order $n$ are *roots* of the polynomial $x^n - 1$. This should help you with Hint 2.

Comment: @Rox For q2, since there are at most d roots of the polynomial, there are at most d elements of order d. For q3, add up the elements *by* order. You know, like, sorting your CD collection by year before counting it.

Comment: @Rox: number of elements of order 1 + number of elements of order 2 + number of elements of order 3 + ...